# In react converting datetime to epoch without rounding

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've looked online but all the methods seem to be rounding the epoch time and not giving an exact answer. Like say if I have a string of "07/25/2022 01:00:00" I want it returned in epoch time of 1658710800 not some rounded number like I have been finding online. How would I do that in react

Comment: `Date.prototype.getTime()` returns milliseconds since epoch. So you first need to convert your string to a date and then milliseconds to seconds. Given `const dateStr = "07/25/2022 01:00:00";` convert your string to date `const date = new Date(dateStr + 'Z');` (if you want to treat the string as local time don't add the `'Z'`) then convert milliseconds to seconds using which ever rounding you want (floor / round / ceil)  `const epoch = Math.floor(date.getTime() / 1000);`, I lean more towards flooring the value and treating it as "it's not a full second so I don't care".

Comment: `not some rounded number` what rounded number are you finding online?